# SphinxSearch: how to get all words with frequencies

Tags: autocomplete, indexing, sphinx, autosuggest

I want to create a 'Did You Mean' feature on my website. For that, I need to build an index table with trigrams of all possible words. Hence I need to have all these words.

I know that's possible using `indexer myindex --buildstops dict.txt 100000 --buildfreqs` command. But I don't want to export to `dict.txt`file the results and then import it with my PHP script. I want to get all the words immediately and directly.

Is there any way to have this approach?

Comment: Whats so wrong with writing to a temporally file and then reading it in?

Comment: Because I don't think it's true way. For example what if exec, shell_exec, system, and another shell commands are disabled on some servers? I want to make my extension to be less server configuration specific.

Comment: Going to need to be able to run cli commands anyway, to start searchd. Could run the command via cron like do with normal indexer command

Answer (score 0):

if the index is a `dict=keywords` format, can use the `indextool --dumpdict` command as an alternative - it writes to STDOUT (so can use with popen etc in PHP).

Comment: Yes, but I don't want to use shell commands. Is there any way to do it via API or SpinxQL?

Comment: Not as far as I know.